# Building robots with high reliability, durability, and battery life

Tags: mobile-robot, battery, reinforcement-learning

I'm involved in research on psychologically plausible models of reinforcement learning, and as such I thought it'd be nice to try and see how well some to the models out there perform in the real world (i.e. sensory-motor learning on a mobile robot). This is already been done in some robotics labs, such Sutton's [implementation of the Horde Architecture on the "Critterbot"](http://webdocs.cs.ualberta.ca/~sutton/papers/horde-aamas-11.pdf). However, these implementations involve robots custom-build by robotics experts in order to deal with the trials and tribulations of learning on a long time-scale:

> "The robot has been
>   designed to withstand the rigors of reinforcement learning
>   experiments; it can drive into walls for hours without damage or burning out its motors, it can dock autonomously
>   with its charging station, and it can run continuously for
>   twelve hours without recharging."

Unfortunately I'm no expert when it comes to designing robots, and don't have access to a high quality machine shop even if I did; I'm stuck with whatever I can buy off-the-self or assemble by hand. Are these constraints common enough for amateur robotics suppliers to cater to, or should I expect to have to start from scratch?

Comment: This question can't be answered in a useful way. Any answer describing the state of the art of robotics, will get out-dated in a couple of months, a year tops. It's also very general.

Comment: Just a pointer to a line of particularity durable and longlasting off-the-self or kit robots would be fine. If a particular company/supplier caters to such needs, then the answer wouldn't be out-dated rapidly.

Comment: Welcome to *robotics* zergylord, but I'm afraid that there is no [*practical, answerable question based on actual problems that you face*](http://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) here. Take a look at [ask] and [about] and if you can edit your question to make it answerable then I would be happy to reopen it.

Comment: How is this too localized? Am I the only person concerned with actuator reliably and the battery life of robots? I read all of those links; which part actually applies to me?

Comment: http://robotics.stackexchange.com/q/554/1460 So asking about battery life in general is too localized and quickly outdated, but asking about battery life constraints on a particular robot model is widely applicable and long lasting knowledge? I'm deeply confused about what the guidelines for this S.E. are...

Comment: Nevermind, found the meta question you guys seem to be talking about: http://meta.robotics.stackexchange.com/q/91/1460. Any chance of reopening if I get rid of "state of the art" in the title?

Comment: @zergylord, now the question is a bit better. Regarding your one-before-last comment, the way you ask the question is something like: "What battery in the market should I use?" which is a search-for-me-and-let-me-know type of question. If you really want to know about how battery life constraints work with respect to how complex the robot is, you could have asked something along the lines of: "Bla bla bla, the more secure, reliable and durable the more battery power I need. How do I decide what is the optimal tradeoff?", and you would get an answer like "It depends on your application"

Comment: Anyway, try to be more specific in your question and sure it would get reopened if it becomes a good question.

Comment: Sorry zergylord, I should have linked to that [meta post](http://meta.robotics.stackexchange.com/q/91/1460) when I made my pre closure comment. I will reopen this for now so we can see if anyone can answer it as it stands, but I will have to be sensitive to future close votes - at the moment it is very close to a [NARQ (not a real question)](http://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions). It would be better if you asked a question about a *real problem you face* along with what you have tried so far to solve it rather than dealing with a hypothetical situation.

Comment: It's not hypothetical, but I see your point about being close to a NARQ. The question is basically that I don't know where to start: e.g. should I be reading on energy efficient actuators and plan to build my bot piece by piece or would modifying a preexisting model, like a roomba, result in better sensor/actuator reliability and battery life?

Comment: I think I see the question you're trying to ask.  You want a robot that's durable enough to withstand long time-scale testing, but you don't know what to look for.  Fill in the blanks for us: "What features does a robot need to be able to do _____ <task> for _______ <time> without mechanical failure?"

Comment: This question is salvageable, but must be edited.  Currently it is a combination of a shopping question ("which amateur robotics suppliers can fill my need?") and lacks a definition of a practical problem (a durable, reliable robot is desired, but no information is given on minimum specifications).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, yes, there are a number of robotics companies catering to just your needs. Specifically which apply to you depends on what type of robot you desire. Naturally cost varies with the complexity and durability. For example if you would be satisfied with a differential drive robot for indoor use then the [iRobot Create](http://www.irobot.com/us/learn/Educators/Create.aspx) may suit your needs. If you need something for outside use then you could look at [Clearpath Robotics](http://www.clearpathrobotics.com/) products. For a full humanoid robot the [Aldeberan Nao](http://www.aldebaran-robotics.com/en/) is a good choice. For quadrotors check out the [AR.Drone Parrot](http://ardrone2.parrot.com/). And I understand [Liquid Robotics](http://liquidr.com/technology/wave-glider.html) offers a good selection of water based robots.

Comment: THanks! Just what I was looking for. Though I've worked with Naos before and I'll vouch for them not being durable lol

Comment: I would be interested in hearing more about what your doing because my interests also lie in RL.

Answer (score 0):

Off-the-shelf robot kits are a good place to start for an amateur. If you're not using system-based kits (i.e. Lego), then they can usually be modified. Mount bumpers around the sides to help it withstand crashes and add a larger battery with a higher milli-amp-hour (mAh) rating for longer battery life. It's tough to provide any more specific solutions than that.